# Infinite Series: Convergence and Divergence tests

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Good Day! I have come across a situation in an exercise which I am unable to figure out. I am sharing the details of the problem are stated below.

The infinite series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n-5)}$ is convergent if we use Limit Comparison Test (LCT) taking $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ .... but using partial fractions, we can write $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n-5)} = \frac{1}{5} [-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{2}{2n-5}]$ ... both the series on the RHS are divergent which means that the given infinite series is divergent. This contradicts the first outcome from LCT. Please, anyone can figure it out what is going wrong here. Thank you!

Comment: For infinite series, in general, it is not true that $\sum_n(a_n+b_n)=\sum_n a_n+\sum_n b_n$

Comment: I think it does ... would you please give an example.

Comment: Your case for example. Or $1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\not=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=\infty-\infty=?$

Comment: Got it ... equality will hold only if both series are convergent. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. If $a_n=b_n=1$, then both $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ diverge, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n-b_n)$ converges.

The statement that you tried to apply only says that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+b_n)$ converges (and that its sum is the sum of the sums of the original series). It claims nothing about what happens if at least one of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks Jose! Can we summarize it as: Given two infinite series $\sum_{n}a_n$ and $\sum_{n}b_n$, then  we have the following. 

1.  If both $\sum_{n}a_n$ and $\sum_{n}b_n$ converges then $\sum_{n}a_n \pm \sum_{n}b_n$ will also converge.

2. If either one of the two diverges then $\sum_{n}a_n \pm \sum_{n}b_n$ will also diverge. 

3. If both series diverge then $\sum_{n}a_n + \sum_{n}b_n$ will diverge but $\sum_{n}a_n - \sum_{n}b_n$ may or may not converge.

Comment: Each of those assertions is correct.